Python Kubernetes MutatingWebhook Not Adding Labels
I have created a Kubernetes MutatingWebhook using a Docker image I built from Python.  The purpose of the webhook is to add labels to any Pod that is launched.  All Kubernetes resources are running fine, however, when new Pods are launched they do not get the expected labels from the MutatingWebhook.  I get this error when I launch a new Pod:
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "add-labels.k8s.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://add-labels-webhook-svc.mutatingwh.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s": dial tcp 10.3.33.250:443: connect: connection refused

Here is the Python webhook code:
import json
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/mutate', methods=['POST'])
def mutate():
    # Read the admission review request
    admission_review = request.get_json()
    print("AdmissionReview Request:", json.dumps(admission_review))

    # Define the patch to add labels
    patch = [
        {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/metadata/labels/live",
            "value": "true"
        },
        {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/metadata/labels/environment",
            "value": "production"
        },
        {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/metadata/labels/service",
            "value": "my-service"
        },
        {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/metadata/labels/version",
            "value": "7.55.2"
        }
    ]

    # Encode the patch to base64
    patch_base64 = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(patch).encode()).decode()

    # Prepare the admission review response
    admission_response = {
        "uid": admission_review['request']['uid'],
        "allowed": True,
        "patchType": "JSONPatch",
        "patch": patch_base64
    }

    # Return the admission review response
    response = {
        "apiVersion": "admission.k8s.io/v1",
        "kind": "AdmissionReview",
        "response": admission_response
    }

    return jsonify(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=443, ssl_context=('tls.crt', 'tls.key'), debug=True)

Here are the various K8s manifest files that I used for the deployment, services, etc.
deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: add-labels-webhook
  namespace: mutatingwh
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: add-labels-webhook
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: add-labels-webhook
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: webhook
          image: 805960120419.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/noc/add-labels-webhook:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 443
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: ecr-secret

service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: add-labels-webhook-svc
  namespace: mutatingwh
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 443
  selector:
    app: add-labels-webhook

mutatingwebhookconfiguration.yaml
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: MutatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  name: add-labels-webhook
webhooks:
  - name: add-labels.k8s.io
    clientConfig:
      service:
        name: add-labels-webhook-svc
        namespace: mutatingwh
        path: "/mutate"
      caBundle: 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
    admissionReviewVersions: ["v1"]
    sideEffects: None
    rules:
      - operations: ["CREATE"]
        apiGroups: [""]
        apiVersions: ["v1"]
        resources: ["pods"]
    failurePolicy: Fail

My question is why is everything running fine, but when new Pods are created they do not get the labels from the Python webhook?
